# Template database population

Tags: atk4

Need to populate a template:

```
     <div id="atk-layout" class="atk-wrapper">
     <?$pastor?>
     <?$missionstatement?>  
     <?$tmissionstatement?>   
     <div id="atk-footer-guard"></div>
     </div>
```

**In the Page I have this:**

```
<?php
class View_Belfry extends View {
function init(){
  parent::init();
  q=$this->api->db->dsql();
  $q->table('gum')->getAll();
  foreach($q as $row){
    switch ($row['sequence']) {
        case 0:
          $Pastor = $row['content'];
          break;
    case 1:
      $MissionStatement = $row['content'];
      break;
            case 2:
              $TMissionStatement = $row['content'];
              break; 
    }
$this->template->set('Pastor',$Pastor);  <<<<<
```

in the above line how do you add more than one Element 
I either get a blank page or one Field displayed using different syntaxes

What is the syntax for multiple content tags in a template. Or am I missing some design feature? I get the first tag or a blank screen. The table field names don't match the template content names because the table field name "section" holds the name.

Like so:
Database table:

```
<?php
class Model_Gum extends Model_Table {
public $table="gum";
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('section');
    $this->addField('content')->type('text');

    $this->addField('publish')->type('boolean');
    $this->addField('sequence');


}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using Agile Toolkit on a very low level. Please read http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/lister and about Models - you define model but you don't really use it. Also http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/template/how could be good.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display array in View.
To display multiple content you need to use Lister, CompleteLister, Grid or CRUD class.

Also you are using dsql for no reason. It's more simple to use model.

```
$m = $this->add('Model_Gum');
```

Now add CompleteLister View (or other).

```
$l = $this->add('Your_Lister');
$l->setModel($m);
```

Create Your_Lister class witch extends on of the lister View and make necessary conditions inside

```
function formatRow(){
    parent::formatRow();
}
```